# Busqueda por rango de fecha en ReactiveMongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, programación-reactiva

como podría expresar en @Query rango de fechas ingresadas como parametros en ReactiveMongoRepository para que realize una busqueda de mis productos.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias por el aporte @JJMADEO, investigando tambien encontre otra forma de hacerlo utilizando las nomenclatura para realizar la bÚsqueda

```
Flux<ManageOperation> findByNumberAccountAndDateOperationBetween(String numberAccount,Date inicio, Date fin);
```

utilizando mis atributos de mi document: `NumberAccount,DateOperation.`

Comment: Por favor no olvides marcar como aceptada alguna de las 2 respuestas, eso ayuda a identificar la pregunta como solucionada.

Answer (score 0):

prueba de esata manera:

```
items.find({
created_at: {
    $gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
    $lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}
})
```

Comment: Por favor amplía tu respuesta agregando detalles de cómo lo que propones ayuda al OP a resolver su problema. Para algunos puede ser clara tu respuesta pero la idea de stack overflow es servir de referencia para muchos visitantes que tengan un problema similar al del OP.

Comment: Si la respuesta es la misma, quiere decir que la pregunta era la misma y hay que cerrarla como duplicada. Podes confirmar eso?